# How to say "he/she is a natural"?

Tags: traducción, modismos

What are some idiomatic/natural-sounding ways of saying the English phrase "He/she is a natural", which implies that someone has a natural talent for something or learned it very easily?

Comment: In the right context, a slangy word would be *bárbaro/a*.

Comment: Rāhula tiene razón acerca de que esto roza lo off-topic. Yo no quiero tomar ninguna acción, porque como moderador mi voto cerraría automática y unilateralmente la pregunta. Quizá además del tag "traducción" esta pregunta debería llevar el tag "solicitud de modismo" y en lugar de intentar traducir "He/she is a natural" buscar una expresión en español para lo mismo. También ayudaría ampliar un poco la pregunta para clarificar qué se busca (traducción o modismo?) y mostrar algo de esfuerzo previo (tal vez con un intento de traducción?) No es un caso claro, así que se verá en las colas de rev.

Comment: Sí, era un comentario, ya borrado. La verdad es que para las preguntas de "traducción" pedimos intento de traducción y/o esfuerzo previo. Yo esta pregunta la veo un poco ambigua, en el sentido de que por el título la entendería como de traducción, pero por el cuerpo más de "solicitud de modismo". No hace falta escribir una parrafada en cada pregunta, pero esta es solo un par de líneas y la verdad es que no le vendría mal extenderla un poco, aclarando la respuesta que se busca (y así nos libramos de problemas). Y sí, en las colas no sale quién o quiénes han votado.

Comment: @Diego - I can see your point and when I read this question earlier I almost voted to close.  I think it has received some good positive voting because lots of us find the question interesting.

Comment: J. Taylor, our respected moderator has been pointing out that strictly speaking, a well-posed translation request should show what you've tried so far -- i.e., where you got stuck.  Or if you're doing a word, phrase or expression request, then you should make clear what tone you're aiming for, and how you would use it in a sentence (i.e. provide some context).  In short, please be careful not to give the impression that you can't be bothered to look in some dictionaries. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Rāhula, lo recuerdo. Intentaré sacar tiempo para revisitar ese comentario. Personalmente creo que, dada la etiqueta y "normativa" del stack, muestra un mayor respeto hacia el resto de usuarios si no tenemos que estar considerando si el post es "técnicamente" off-topic. Tampoco creo que el esfuerzo en redactar una buena pregunta sea "mera apariencia" o innecesario.

Comment: @aparente001, I agree with you. I don't think that the problem is this question per se, but this question but this question in the context of our stack's recommendations on how to ask a good questions and what we consider on-topic. I would hate to close someone's question due to "lack of effort" or similar and being pointed out to this question and told "but, it's the same case as this other one!" And I think that the ambiguity on this question could easily be addressed.

Comment: @Diego - I do think that our eager beaver regular participants should and can continue to train themselves to hold back with answering incomplete questions, as a way of training askers to ask well-posed questions.  But may I take a step back and invite everyone to take this discussion to Meta instead of having it here?  E.g. https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2681/9385.  Or perhaps a new question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Besides *innato* there is also the word [nato](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=QHeXPu2) defined like this:

> Del lat. natus 'nacido'.
>
> 1. adj. Dicho de un título de honor o de un cargo: Que va anejo al empleo o a la calidad de alguien.
> 2. adj. Dicho de una aptitud o de una cualidad: innata.
> 3. adj. Que tiene predisposición connatural para algo. Es un deportista nato.

As shown on the same RAE example:

- Es un deportista nato = He is a natural for sports.

*Nato* and *innato* are almost synonyms but their use is a little different. See the following examples

Jefe nato,
Líder nato,
Miembro nato,
Conversador nato,

Talento innato,
Don innato,
Miedo innato a las alturas,
Potencial innato.

Comment: @DGaleano, the pattern in your examples seems to be clear: **nato** for people, **innato** for gifts and talents.

Answer (score 1):

Lo normal es decir que tiene un talento **innato**:

> **[innato, ta.](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?w=innato)**
>   Del lat. *innātus*, part. pas. de *innasci* 'nacer en', 'producirse'.
>
> 1. adj. Connatural y como nacido con la persona misma.

Ejemplo: *«Juan toca muy bien el piano, tiene un talento **innato**.»*

Aunque también valdría decir simplemente que tiene un talento **natural**, igual que en inglés.